# How can an Earth-like planet support two moons of different sizes

Tags: planets, moons, tides, eclipses

In my world, I need to have two moons orbiting an Earth-like planet. I need the extreme tides as they play a big part for a cultural detail. The first moon should be roughly the size of our own moon, while the second one is smaller, it doesn't matter exactly how much. The two moons should also be visible together regularly. If there is an eclipse between the two or the two and the sun, it would roughly once an earth year, it would be perfect. Because I am not an expert at this field, I am not sure how that would look like. How much influenced would the tides be? What would be observable from the inhabitants of the planet? What about full moons? On what axis/ orbits should each moon be to achieve this? Is it even possible?

The overall question is how would such a moon system work?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please narrow down to a single question, as per our [help]

Comment: If you look on the right here, under "related", you will see many questions dealing with 2 moons. What is not answered by those questions?

Comment: I can't find how it would look like from the inhabitants, or the specifics such as tides and eclipses for the two moons of different size with similar orbit. I also don't understand how the orbit itself would work. (Thank you for your help, I am new to this amazing community)